# Can Google Analytics track Javascript or .NET version usage?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, analytics, tracking

I know that Google Analytics requires javascript to work, so I doubt it tracks that.  But what about .NET version?  Is there a way to view what .NET versions people are using on my site using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 5):

Why?

The .NET version users have on their machines makes is immaterial. In fact whether they have .NET on their machine or not is immaterial. Any .NET code in your site is run *server* side not *client* side.

Comment: .Net version may be interesting to people who want to distribute a client app requiring a certain version.

Comment: @Michael - that may well be true, but didn't appear to be what the OP was asking.

Comment: isn't it? As you say, .NET matters primarily on the server and on the client, not so much in the browser. So assuming OP is competent (and why not start with that assumption?), it goes to reason that the motivation had to do with viability of client or Silverlight software. That at least seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @MichaelTeper The OP asks, "Is there a way to view what .NET versions people **are using on my site** using Google Analytics?" .NET is not used to run the JavaScript code in the browser; asking the version of .NET they are using on his site doesn't make sense. If he used ASP.NET to run his site, then he is running it.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer reports the version of .NET installed in its user agent string. If Google Analytics shows you the user agent strings for the browsers used to connect to your server, you should be able to verify the version of .NET.

Some browsers allow users to change the user agent string used when connecting to web sites; you could think a user has installed .NET when it's not true.

I am not sure what the importance of knowing that is, though.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, you can't get at the actual user agent string data with Google Analytics, and GA does not yet break out .Net version info.